# SQL Query with Multiple condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that makes a month worth of summary, but I have a condition that makes it tough.

Before our procedure is that to just summarize the whole month but due to the change I need to implement this new condition. The new condition is that I need to search Jan 1, 2019 to Jan 6, 2019 till 11PM then the rest of the month is till 10PM

Basically I need to Summarize Jan 1 - 6 till 11PM AND Summarize Jan 7- Jan 31 till 10PM then Add both results.

```
SELECT  timeStamp, exit_coilid, exit_gaptime, new_gaptime, exit_width
FROM exitCoilData
JOIN NewGapTime
ON exitCoilData.exit_Coilid = NewGapTime.coilid
WHERE (
    timeStamp > ('1/1/2019') 
    AND 
    timeStamp <= ('1/6/2019 11:00PM')
    )
AND
    (
    timeStamp > ('1/7/2019 10:00PM') 
    AND 
    timeStamp <= DATEADD("m",1, '1/1/2019 10:00PM')
    )
```

Comment: @User LOL that solves my Problem Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Write 2 querys whit the differents date and use "UNION" like this, you must return the same number of field and types in both querys

```
SELECT firstName, lastName, company FROM businessContacts
UNION
SELECT firstName, lastName, NULL FROM nonBusinessContacts
```

Comment: I have tried this method, but I am maintaining an old website and I seem to introduce more bugs than fixing it also I am not rather familiar with VBscript where this script is implemented, so I was thinking used whats working. I do agree that this is a terrible way of thinking

Answer (score 0):

Your `WHERE` clause could be simplified (made easier to read :) ) using `BETWEEN`. Also, as already mentioned, you need simply `OR` operator (I used more familiar to me date format, but it isn't relevant to answer):

```
WHERE timeStamp BETWEEN '2019-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-01-06 23:00:00'
   OR timeStamp BETWEEN '2019-01-07 00:00:00' AND '2019-01-31 22:00:00'
```

Comment: I have tried this method, but I am maintaining an old website and I seem to introduce more bugs than fixing it also I am not rather familiar with VBscript where this script is implemented, so I was thinking used whats working. I do agree that this is a terrible way of thinking